# Spring cloud starter task : AnnotationConfigApplicationContext has been closed already

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-cloud-task

Building new project using spring batch and Spring cloud tasks using spring boot application.

I am getting following error while doing the integration with Spring Cloud Flow Tasks.

Here is the error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@45c2f888 has been closed already
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.assertBeanFactoryActive(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1073)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1106)
>       at org.springframework.boot.devtools.autoconfigure.ConditionEvaluationDeltaLoggingListener.onApplicationEvent(ConditionEvaluationDeltaLoggingListener.java:43)
>       at org.springframework.boot.devtools.autoconfigure.ConditionEvaluationDeltaLoggingListener.onApplicationEvent(ConditionEvaluationDeltaLoggingListener.java:33)
>       at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
>       at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
>       at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:400)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:354)
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.running(EventPublishingRunListener.java:103)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.running(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:78)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:343)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243)
>       at com.ranker.batch_v2.BatchV2Application.main(BatchV2Application.java:14)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)

POM configuration used to build the project:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.ranker</groupId>
  <artifactId>batch_v2</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>batch_v2</name>
  <description>Ranker Batch</description>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-batch -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <!-- exclude tomcat jdbc connection pool, use HikariCP -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
          <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- exclude tomcat-jdbc, Spring Boot will use HikariCP automatically  -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.zaxxer/HikariCP -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
      <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-task-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-task-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>


</project>
```

Please advice me to fix the issue, Kind of time sensitive any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: I presume this is a new project from Spring Initializr (start.spring.io)?

Comment: Can you share also your taks's config? Have you identified if the error is thrown initializing spring context or during your task execution? I saw similar errors before. In my case was related with the actual task code not keeping the app running (reactive code) so spring was closing as soon as it starts up. How are you executing your task: CommandLineRunner?

Comment: Yea command line runner "mvnw spring-boot:run". I think it was failing when try to boot the application itself. but i can double check and let you know about it

Comment: When I said `CommandLineRunner` I meant in the code, the mechanism you implemented to invoke your actual task code. What I was looking for is if your task starts to shutdown before your task's code completes.

Comment: @geek, Did you get any solution for this?